# Value of type 'Reactive<UITextField>' has no member 'text'

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming

I have a code like this:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
tvSearchItem.rx.text.orEmpty
    .filter { text in text.count >= 3 }
    .flatMapLatest { text in cnfClient.getCNFacts(search: text, searchType: "t:t") }
    .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) {  row, element, cell in
        if self.shouldShowSearchResults {
            cell.textLabel?.text = element["result"]!
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = element["location"]!
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

but Xcode gives me:

Value of type 'Reactive' has no member 'text'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify which Reactive library you're using?  Also, it'd be much easier to help if you gave a simplified version of the complete file, including the import statements, and trimming everything else out leaving only the line that causes the bug.  Thanks!

Comment: I create a demo, and It go well.  Have you import 'RxCocoa'?
When I remove it, I get a error as same as you have.

Comment: @jperl, sorry for that, it's RxSwift

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `import RxCocoa` included in the file, along with `import RxSwift`